# how to start axis label at zero?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'am trying to draw x-axis with labels using d3.js,I have a data array of years from 1950 - 2015,i intend to plot them on x-axis,starting from year 0,but my code outputs x-axis which starts at the minimum value of the array,if edit array with 0 as minimum value,then x-axis labels change.Any hint at where iam doing wrong?

what my code outputs: 1950...1955....1960

output when year 0 is included which is not what i want:
 0....200....400..........2015

what i intend to output: 0....1950....1955....

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/renx777/pen/wrOLMr?editors=0010)

```
   $.getJSON(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json",
      function(x) {
        var rawData = x.data;
        var yearData = [];
        var gdpData = [];
        var width = 1020;
        var height = 100;
        for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
          yearData.push(rawData[0][0]);
          gdpData.push(rawData[1][1]);
        }

        //values which should be labeled on x-axis
        var years = [
          1950,
          1955,
          1960,
          1965,
          1970,
          1980,
          1985,
          1990,
          2000,
          2005,
          2010,
          2015
        ];
        var svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append('g');


        var x_domain = d3.extent(years, function(d) {
          return d;
        });

        var xscale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(x_domain)
        .nice()
        .range([20, 600]);

        var x_axis = d3
        .axisBottom()
        .scale(xscale)
        .ticks(11);

        svg
          .append("g")
          .call(x_axis);

      }
    );
```

Comment: Do you want it to scale? Because if you have a range of 0..2015, those years in your list are going to be pretty cramped on the right. Or do you want it to "skip a bit" in the middle?

Comment: axis should start at 0 and next value should be 1950,1955,...2015 and so on

**0....1950...1955....1960............2015**

is there a way to label ticks straight from array values without scaling?

Comment: just saw your edit to your comment. So you don't want *any* scale? E.g. the space between 1990 and 2000 should be the same as the space between 2000 and 2005?

Comment: yes,i dont want the values to scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, what you're looking for is a `Point` scale instead of a `Linear` scale, and include the `0` value in your array.

You can use the `years` array directly as the `domain` and the point scale will then default to using these values for `tickValues`.

```js
$.getJSON(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json",
      function(x) {
        var rawData = x.data;
        var yearData = [];
        var gdpData = [];
        var width = 1020;
        var height = 100;
        for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
          yearData.push(rawData[0][0]);
          gdpData.push(rawData[1][1]);
        }

        //values which should be labeled on x-axis
        var years = [0, // including the 0
          1950,1955,1960,1965,1970,1980,1985,1990,2000,2005,2010,2015];
        var svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append('g');

        var xscale = d3
        .scalePoint() // instead of Linear
        .domain(years) // can use the years array directly as domain
        .range([20,600]);

        var x_axis = d3
        .axisBottom()
        .scale(xscale);

        svg
          .append("g")
          .call(x_axis);

      }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tickValues is really useful,when you just want to label the values from array ,but as you can see in output,adding 0 skews up the axis,if you remove 0,it works fine

Comment: ok, now I know what you're looking for I've updated the answer - should do what you require

Comment: I just realized with the Point scale you don't even need to explicitly set `tickValues` so I've updated the answer accordingly